Only first differencing the independent variable?
I am trying to study the relationship between income and preferences for redistribution. I have a panel dataset.
I can simply the model (1): preferences = alpha + income + e. However, I'm also interested in the change in income rather than the level variable. In that case I might run (2) preferences = alpha + ∆income + e.
My question is, does only first differencing the income variable okay? Additionally, is including ∆income any different from just including the level of income? Cause even if model (1) is using level variables, they do change across years, so I'm now a bit confused if I will even get different results by first differencing income. Thanks!

Do you have panel data? Or do you have cross-section and only know income at time t and t-1?

How is your dependent variable quantified?

@dimitriy I have a panel data for 7 years

@AlecosPapadopoulos it's an ordinal scale from 1 (very likely) to 6 (very unlikely)

I'll start with your second question. The most flexible (linear) version of the CEF model says the expected rating depends on income today and income in the last period:
$$E[y_{t} \vert i_t, i_{t-1}] = \alpha + \beta_1 \cdot i_t + \beta_2 \cdot i_{t-1}$$
Here the timing of income matters for the effect as long as $\beta_1 \ne \beta_2$.
Including only today's income means forcing $\beta_2 = 0$ or saying that income yesterday does not matter:
$$E[y_{t} \vert i_t, i_{t-1}] = \tilde \alpha + \tilde\beta_1 \cdot i_t $$
First-differencing income is equivalent to the restriction that $ \beta_2 = - \beta_1 =\hat \beta $ since:
$$E[y_{t} \vert i_t, i_{t-1}] = \alpha + \beta_1 \cdot i_t - \beta_1 \cdot i_{t-1} = \hat\alpha + \hat \beta \cdot (i_t - i_{t-1})= \hat \alpha + \hat \beta \cdot \Delta i$$
This makes income today and yesterday fungible: one more dollar today has the same effect as losing a dollar yesterday.
All this means the answer to your second question is a yes: they are generally different. Note that $\beta_1 \ne \tilde\beta_1 \ne  \hat \beta $, since they all correspond to different comparisons.
Is only differencing income OK? This is a more complicated question. If you are worried that there is some omitted factor that alters both preferences and income, then you should also difference the outcome to purge it. This can help reduce bias if that factor is time-invariant. One example might be altruistic preferences that favor both redistribution and cause employment in the non-profit sector, where salaries are lower. But the advice here depends on the setting and your model for how these political opinions form.
